# Update currentTime with multiple audio sources

Tags: javascript, html

**UPDATE**
**I fixed it with the following code!**

```
const songPick = document.querySelector("select");
const toggle = document.querySelector(".toggle");
const audio = document.querySelector('audio[src="Kalliope.mp3"]');
toggle.addEventListener("click", pauseOrPlay);
songPick.addEventListener("change", audioSource);

function audioSource() {
    audio.src = songPick.value;
}

function pauseOrPlay() {
    if(!audio.paused && !audio.ended) {
        audio.pause();
        toggle.innerHTML = '<i class="fa fa-play" aria-hidden="true"></i>';
    }else{
        audio.play();
        toggle.innerHTML = '<i class="fa fa-pause" aria-hidden="true"></i>';
    }
}
```

I trying to make a custom made audio player. I have one problem when I pause and play the music it don´t go back to the current time before I paused the audio, instead it plays it from the beginning. I can make it work when I use one source but I have multiple audio sources.

```
<article class="music__player">
    <p>Välj en sång</p>
    <select name="Song pick">
        <option value="Kalliope.mp3" selected>Kalliope</option>
        <option value="Unknown Planet.mp3">Unknown Planet</option>
        <option value="Space Loop.wav">Space Loop</option>
        <option value="Autumn Nights.mp3">Autumn Nights</option>
    </select>
    <img src="space-160x160.jpg" alt="Kalliope Image">
    <div class="played__time"></div>
    <audio src=""></audio>
    <div class="audio-controls">
        <button class="audio__button toggle" title="Play Audio" >
            <i class="fa fa-play" aria-hidden="true"></i>
        </button>
        <button class="audio__button stop" title="Stop Audio">
            <i class="fa fa-stop" aria-hidden="true"></i>
        </button>
        <button class="audio__button" title="Step Forward" data-skip="10">
            <i class="fa fa-step-forward" aria-hidden="true"></i>
        </button>
        <button class="audio__button" title="Step Backwards" data-skip="-10">
            <i class="fa fa-step-backward" aria-hidden="true"></i>
        </button>
    </div>
</article>

const songPick = document.querySelector("select");
const toggle = document.querySelector(".toggle");
const audio = document.querySelector('audio[src=""]');
toggle.addEventListener("click", pauseOrPlay);
let audioTime;

function pauseOrPlay() {
    if(!audio.paused && !audio.ended) {
        audio.src = songPick.value;
        audio.pause();
        toggle.innerHTML = '<i class="fa fa-play" aria-hidden="true"></i>';
    }else{
        if(audioTime > 0)
        {
            audio.currentTime = audioTime;
        }
        audio.src = songPick.value;
        audio.play();
        toggle.innerHTML = '<i class="fa fa-pause" aria-hidden="true"></i>';
    }
}

audio.addEventListener("timechange", function () {
    audioTime = audio.currentTime;
});
```

Comment: Its because you are reloading the song 'audio.src ='  needs to be somewhere else not in your play pause method...

Comment: Thanks i fixed it!